# How to create forwarding rule with multiple ports google cloud (compute)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud, forwarding

I'm trying to set up a network-based load balancing service on google cloud (compute). The last step to create it is to add a forwarding rule.

My service requires multiple ports to be forwarded, looking at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/forwarding-rules/create) it seems possible (unless I'm mistaken).

`--ports=[PORT | START_PORT-END_PORT],[[PORT | START_PORT-END_PORT],…]`

I have tried the following:

```
gcloud compute forwarding-rules create example-forwarding-rule \
    --region europe-west1 \
    --ports 80 443 3000-4000 6001 \
    --address example-address \
    --target-pool example-target-pool
```

And I get the following error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.forwarding-rules.create) Invalid value for [--ports]: Must specify consecutive ports at this time.

I've also tried adding spaces:

```
gcloud compute forwarding-rules create example-forwarding-rule \
    --region europe-west1 \
    --ports 80 443 3000-4000 6001 \
    --address example-address \
    --target-pool example-target-pool
```

Or removing the comma all together:

```
gcloud compute forwarding-rules create example-forwarding-rule \
    --region europe-west1 \
    --ports 80 443 3000-4000 6001 \
    --address example-address \
    --target-pool example-target-pool
```

And I get the following error for both:

> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.forwarding-rules.create) unrecognized arguments

Is it possible to specify mutliple ports and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `--ports` flag only supports specifying overlapping or adjacent ranges so gCloud SDK can merge the ranges into a single contiguous range.

See `ports` section in https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/network/forwarding-rules which has more clear explanation.

> [Optional] A single port or single contiguous port range, ranging from low to high, for which this forwarding rule matches.